# Black image when rendering PDF to image with UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, pdfkit

We have been noticing since release iOS 17, that our code which renders `PDFPage` objects to images was randomly failing (while no error is logged) and produced full black images. This problem seems to only occur on old devices (iPad Pro 2017 and 2018) but not on recent ones.

I mention that this portion code has been running for several years in our app without any issue from iOS10 to iOS16.

```
    let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
    renderFormat.opaque = true
    renderFormat.scale = CGFloat(scale)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size, format: renderFormat)
    let mainImage = renderer.image { context in
        // Setup drawing context
        context.cgContext.setShouldAntialias(false)
        context.cgContext.setShouldSmoothFonts(false)
        context.cgContext.setAllowsFontSmoothing(false)
        context.cgContext.setShouldSubpixelPositionFonts(true)
        context.cgContext.setShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts(true)
        
        // Draw pdf page 
        context.saveGState()
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        context.clip(to: rect)
        context.fill(rect)
        page.draw(with: .cropBox, to: context)
        context.restoreGState()
   }
```

Did anyone encountered a similar issue?

Is there any mean to get an error at least in such cases ?

Thanks for any help or advice on this issue.

Comment: I would start by experimenting with disabling some of the options in the context setup and seeing if it renders properly without one or all of them. Let me know if you need some further help with this.